# Не могу понять как реализовать метод PlayerAttack()

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Не могу понять как реализовать метод `PlayerAttack()`, в котором необходимо вычесть от значения здоровья врага класса `Opponent` значение, равное урону оружия игрока.

То, что получилось придумать - не работает.

```
class Guns:
    def __init__ (self,name, power):
        self.gun_name = name
        self.gun_power = power

    def Display_Weapon(self):
        print("Оружие - {0}, Урон - {1}".format(self.gun_name, self.gun_power))


class Player:
    def __init__(self, health, my_gun):
        self.health = health
        self.my_gun = my_gun
        
    def Display_Player_Info(self):
        print("Ваше здоровье = {0}, Ваше оружие - {1} (Урон = {2}".format(self.health, self.my_gun.gun_name, self.my_gun.gun_power))
        
    def PlayerAttack(self):
        Opponent.opp_health.opp_hp -= self.my_gun.my_power
        print("Здоровье противника: {0}".format(Opponent.opp_health.opp_hp))
        
    
class Opponent:
    def __init__(self, name, opp_dmg, opp_hp):
        self.opp_damage = opp_dmg
        self.opp_health = opp_hp
        self.name = name
        print("""Появился враг: {0}
        Здоровье врага: {1}""".format(name, opp_hp))

pistol = Guns("Pistol", 10)
monster = Opponent("Monster",10, 15)
hman = Player(10, pistol)
hman.PlayerAttack()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, health, my_gun, monster):                 # + monster
        super().__init__()
        self.health = health
        self.my_gun = my_gun
        self.monster = monster
            
    def Display_Player_Info(self):
        print("Ваше здоровье = {0}, Ваше оружие - {1} (Урон = {2}"\
            .format(self.health, self.my_gun.gun_name, self.my_gun.gun_power))
            
    def PlayerAttack(self):
#        Opponent.opp_health.opp_hp -= self.my_gun.my_power
#        print("Здоровье противника: {0}".format(Opponent.opp_health.opp_hp))
        
        self.monster.opp_health -= self.my_gun.gun_power
        print("Здоровье противника: {0}".format(self.monster.opp_health))
            
        
class Opponent:
    def __init__(self, name, opp_dmg, opp_hp):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.opp_damage = opp_dmg
        self.opp_health = opp_hp

        print("""Появился враг: {0}
        Здоровье врага: {1}""".format(name, opp_hp))


class Guns:
    def __init__ (self, name, power):
        super().__init__()
        self.gun_name = name
        self.gun_power = power
        
    def Display_Weapon(self):
        print("Оружие - {0}, Урон - {1}".format(self.gun_name, self.gun_power))

        
pistol = Guns("Pistol", 10)
monster = Opponent("Monster", 10, 15)

hman = Player(10, pistol, monster)                               # + monster
hman.PlayerAttack()
```

Comment: @Константин сто не так?